# multiple files upload in sequential order in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, upload

I am working on the stuff multiple files uploading one by one(sequential upload). If suppose I have 10 files, then, I need to upload these files one by one sequentially. I mean the second file has to wait till the first file to be uploaded. when the first file upload is completed and it should wait for the success response **then only** the second file should start the upload process, then after, the third one and should goes on likewise.

Am using the ng-file-upload module [https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload] for the upload portion and am also having one sample link over here [http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/2vq88rfs/136/] for the sample uploading files one by one. But, it is still not uploading the files one by one sequentially.

My aim is that I need to [i should] upload the files one by one **sequentially not concurrently**.

Any help on this please?

```
angular.forEach(files, function(file) {


                    var fileValidOutput = validateAssets(file);      //this is my custom custom validation
                    var noDuplicate = checkDuplicateFiles(file.name); //this is my custom custom validation

                    if (!file.$error && noDuplicate == true && fileValidOutput.valid == true) {

                        params.type = fileValidOutput.type; //this is my custom parameter to be passed
                        console.log("File Type: " + params.type);

                        file.upload = Upload.upload({
                            url: uploadURL,
                            data: {
                                file: file
                            },
                            params: params   ////this is my custom parameters
                        });

                        file.upload.then(function(response) {
                            $timeout(function() {
                                file.result = response.data;

                                console.log('success in uploading asset');
                                sessionRecentUploadService.uploadStatus="Uploaded...";
                            });
                        }, function(response) {
                            if (response.status > 0)
                                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                        }, function(evt) {
                            file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                        });

                    }

                });
```

Comment: You can use promises. So you can pass a single element to your upload function and as soon as you get a response file was uploaded then pass second element. Also if you use promises then it will support concurrent execution also you will get to know which file is not uploaded. 
I tried to pull a JsFiddle but it is not opening.

Comment: And if some upload fails, should all the batch fail too?

Comment: @ShardulPendse,  I have already the used the promise (then), but, it was not working...
For sample, just go here https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload and on the samples head; you can find the links, the second link is what i mentioned here..

Comment: Can you please pass parameter file as file[i]. i is an index of forEach.

Comment: @ShardulPendse, I did the same, but, no use.... it still is not working...